TFS to run a .bat file as an administrator
I have a release pipeline task that runs a .bat file. This .bat file creates a Windows Process and Starts it. So this .bat file should run as an admin . How the TFS agent will run this .bat file as an admin? . The user that runs the VSTS agent has already admin rights on the machine and the process and vsts agent are on the same machine.
My .bat file
sc create PortalWinService binPath= "E:\TestSites\Portal\src\Portal.exe"  
 
sc failure PortalWinService actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/""/60000 reset= 86400
sc start PortalWinService 
sc config PortalWinService start=auto



How the TFS agent will run this .bat file as an admin? . The user that runs the VSTS agent has already admin rights on the machine and the process and vsts agent are on the same machine.

If the account when you setup VSTS agent has already admin rights, it will use this account to run the .bat in pipeline, which means it has already run as admin.
You can add a powershell task with whoami to double confirm the account.

To execute the bat file, you can simply store the bat file in repo, then run in commandline task:



Yes the agent user has admin rights. i think the prompt has to do with User Account Control

Is the account the administrator account? or a member of the admin group on the agent? Please try with the administrator account.

is member of the admin group. I cannot use the administrator account. Is there another way ?

I can run the bat file with common admin user. May i know what appearance on your side? and please locate which command cause the problem. To run as admin, you can temporarily change the account to administrator(link) or add content in your bat file, please check the link for the details.
